# javascript simulate text entry by name not id

Tags: javascript, html, string

So i know i can run a javascript to autmoatically fill a text field by ID using something like this.

```
document.getElementById('user_name').value='admin';return false;
```

But how can the same be done for a textfield without an id but with a name? What do i have to change in my above code?

```
<input class="inputw" size="15" name="phoneNumber" value="1234567890" maxlength="19">
```

I tried something like getElementbyName but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot "s" letter.

```
document.getElementsByName("phoneNumber")[0].value = "admin";
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends if there are multiple fields with the same name or not. `IDs` have to be unique `name` does not. If there is only one field where `name=phoneNumber` then try this:

```
document.getElementsByName('phoneNumber')[0].value='admin';
```

Looks like you were missing the 's' from `.getElementsByName`

Have a look here for more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName.

> .getElementsByName() - Returns a list of elements with a given name in the (X)HTML document.

If there are multiple elements with the same name the index in the square brackets `[0]` would change to the one you want to access or you could use a `for` loop to act on each one in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName):

```
document.getElementsByName('phoneNumber')[0].value='admin';return false;
```

The [0] is the element in the collection you want to target. If there's only one just use `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByName(name)`, this will return an array of the elements with said name. Specify the index of the element you want to change:

```
document.getElementsByName('phoneNumber')[0].value = 'test';
```